# Can't add to ul after empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm emptying a UL using jquery then I'm trying to add a new `<li>` after that however it's not adding the `<li>`

```
$('#pre-list').empty(); //Remove prelist
$("#pre-list ol").append('<li>' + $('#lstBox1').val() + '</li>');
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Looks like ```ol``` is removed. try this instead. ```("#pre-list ol").empty().append('<li>' + $('#lstBox1').val() + '</li>');```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to select an element that does not exist (`ol`). You probably meant to do this:

```
$('#pre-list ol').empty(); //Remove prelist
$("#pre-list ol").append('<li>' + $('#lstBox1').val() + '</li>');
```